# JavaScript: instanceof operator

Tags: javascript, prototype

First code:

```
function MyConstructor() {}
var myobject = new MyConstructor();
MyConstructor.prototype = {};

[ myobject instanceof MyConstructor,   // false - why?
myobject.constructor == MyConstructor, // true
myobject instanceof Object ]           // true
```

even though `MyConstructor.prototype` is replaced `myobject` still inherits the properties from `Myconstructor.prototype`. So why is `myobject instanceOf Myconstuctor` false?

```
function MyConstructor() {}
MyConstructor.prototype = {};
var myobject = new MyConstructor();
myobject instanceof MyConstructor  // true (it is because myobject still inherits from
                                   // Myconstructor.prototype although it has been replaced)
```

second:

```
 function MyConstructor() {}
 MyConstructor.prototype = {};
 var myobject = new MyConstructor();

 myobject.constructor == MyConstructor;  // false (accepted )
```

So if myobject.constructor is Object why the first: example not pointing it, how can the `myobject.constructor` still points to `MyConstructor` since `Myconstructor.prototype` has changed in first example.

Can you clarify this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though MyConstructor.prototype is replaced myobject still inherits the properties from Myconstructor.prototype.

No. It inherits from the old object which was replaced. And since that object is `!== MyConstructor.prototype`, the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) will yield false. In your second example, `myobject` inherits from the new prototype (the current `MyConstructor.prototype`), and that's what `instanceof` tells you.

> So if myobject.constructor

The `constructor` property is completely unrelated to `instanceof`.

```
function Constructor() {}
var oldProto = Constructor.prototype;
var oldInstance = new Constructor();

Constructor.prototype = {constructor:"something else"};
var newProto = Constructor.prototype;
var newInstance = new Constructor();

// all these are true:
Object.getPrototypeOf(oldInstance) === oldProto;
Object.getPrototypeOf(newInstance) == newProto;
oldProto !== newProto;
oldProto.constructor === Constructor; // was set implicitly on creating the function
oldInstance.constructor === oldProto.constructor; // inherited
newProto.constructor === "something else"; // if not explicitly set, comes from Object.prototype
newInstance.constructor === newProto.constructor; // inherited

Constructor.prototype === newProto;
newInstance instanceof Constructor; // because the above

Constructor.prototype !== oldProto;
! (oldInstance instanceof Constructor) // because the above
```

Comment: oo that way can we set the construtor property?really good post

Comment: You can set nearly every property (there are only a few non-writable ones).

Comment: u made mistake setting oldProto.constructor==Constructor ,it should be oldInstance.constructor==constructor

Comment: I did not set it. And no, both expressions are true

Comment: as per your reply if i do {}.constructor="foo" and check {}.constructor ,the result is again the same Object why so?

Comment: Beacause `{}` and `{}` are different objects? You did not set the "constructor" property of the second, so it falls back to the inherited one from Object.prototype.

Comment: i was really unknown about that.Today taught me a lot

Comment: plz tell me are internal prototype treated as a link or value will be set to it?