# Set function prototype to null has no effect to newly created javascript object

Tags: javascript, function

I am using the following code:

```
function Tmp(){}
var tmp = new Tmp()
Tmp.prototype.f1 = function(){console.log("f1");}

tmp.f1() -> output: f1 
Tmp.prototype.f1 = function(){console.log("f1 update");}
tmp.f1() -> output: f1 update

//this is confusing
Tmp.prototype = null;
tmp.f1() -> output still: f1 update
```

My question is: when I set Tmp.prototype = null; why it has no effect to tmp.f1(). In other words, the tmp.f1() still output the same result. My understanding is that tmp.f1() will recursively check the property within the prototype chain and if the method is available, then the method is called. But by setting Tmp.prototype = null, I expect that tmp.f1 will be undefined, but it's not the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Because *tmp* gets its `[[Prototype]]` assigned when it's created, so it doesn't matter if you assign a new object as the constructor's prototype, any instances created up to that point still reference the old prototype object. You can check with [*getPrototypeOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getprototypeof).

Comment: @RobG can u provide some link , where i can read about this in detail and what to do if we have to update prototype later, any workaround ?

Comment: @aishwatsingh: it seems that if you want to update a prototype later, you have to loop through properties of prototype object. What I did in the example is creating the whole new object so it won't have any effect, because existing object's prototype still refer to the old created object

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568239/javascriptinstanceof-operator)

Comment: Btw, setting `.prototype` to `null` will not actually create instances with `null` as their prototype (like `Object.create(null)` does), they will be made to inherit from `Object.prototype` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best reference in the specification is to [*9.1.14 OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor).

However, you can test this yourself.

```js
// Constructor, has a default prototype object that
// is a plain Object
function Foo(){}

// Instance has its internal [[Prototype]] set to the
// constructor's prototype when it's created
var foo = new Foo();

// See?
document.write(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === Foo.prototype); // true

// Keep reference to Foo.prototpye
var originalFooProto = Foo.prototype;

// Change Foo.prototype
Foo.prototype = {};

// Create another instance
foo2 = new Foo();

// Current Foo.prototype is not original
document.write('<br>' + (originalFooProto === Foo.prototype)) // false 

// foo's internal prototype is not Foo's new prototype
document.write('<br>' + (Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === Foo.prototype)) // false 

// foo's internal prototype is still the old Foo.prototype
document.write('<br>' + (Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === originalFooProto)) // true 

// foo2's internal prototype is the new Foo.prototype
document.write('<br>' + (Object.getPrototypeOf(foo2) === Foo.prototype)) // true
```